# How to iterate and change an item in-place in a list inside a dict

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

I have some lists as values keys in a dict. Is there some way to iterate through the dict to perform changes in-place on the lists?

```
dictio = {
    'A' : ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'],
    'B' : ['item4', 'item5', 'item3']
}
```

Supposing that I want to alter all the items on both keys:

```
if dictio[key] == 'item3'
    //change all occurences in all lists...
```

I've tried to loop through the dict with a `for` loop and `dict.items()` but can't figure out how.

Comment: You can loop over dict keys and get the value of key which will give you list then iterate over it again and then check your condition

Comment: What is your desired i/p & o/p?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.
Iterating through a dict is covered in any dict tutorial.  Replacing a list element is covered in any list tutorial.

Comment: Sorry for that. I'll try harder.

Answer (score 0):

```
dictio = {
    'A' : ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'],
    'B' : ['item4', 'item5', 'item3']
}

for key, value in dictio.items():
    dictio[key] = ['new_item3' if item == 'item3' else item for item in value]

print(dictio)
```

output

```
{'A': ['item1', 'item2', 'new_item3'], 'B': ['item4', 'item5', 'new_item3']}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to test if your value is in the list and change like shown below:

```
for k,v in dictio.items():
    if 'item3' in v:
        #change value here
        v.pop(v.index('item3'))
        v.append("new Item")
```

Answer (score 0):

A combination of a loop and a list comprehension, like this:

```
dictio = { 
    'A' : ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'],
    'B' : ['item4', 'item5', 'item3']
}

for key in dictio.keys():
    dictio[key] = [ 'replaced' if x == 'item3' else x for x in dictio[key]]

print(dictio)
```

Outputs:

```
{'A': ['item1', 'item2', 'replaced'], 'B': ['item4', 'item5', 'replaced']}
```

Comment: That is... Thanks for the help!